WooCommerce - Empty Cart Page Reload issue
I have an issue when i remove product from the cart and the page refresh to the empty cart page. I use this inside my functions.php file to modify the empty cart page :
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 'custom_empty_cart_message', 10 );

function custom_empty_cart_message() {
    $html  = '<h1 class="woocommerce-cart-title">Cart</h1>';
    $html .= '<div class="cart-empty"><p class="cart-empty">';
    $html .= '<p class="cart-empty cart-empty_text">Your cart is currently empty.</p>';
    $html .= '<img fetchpriority="high" decoding="async" width="540" height="540" src="https://myurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/empty_bento.jpeg" alt="empty_bento" class="empty_bento" sizes="(max-width: 740px) 100vw, 740px">';

    echo $html . '</p></div>';
    echo do_shortcode( '[woo_product_slider id="2994"]' );
}

The first part is working but then the shortcode slider is not rendered, i have an infinite loading wheel.
If i manually refresh the page a second time, everything loads correctly and works.
How can i successfully render the shortcode on first page reload ?

Insert a javascript snippet that reloads the page and see if it works.

I tried to insert javascript inside my function "custom_empty_cart_message" but that's not working. If i'm on the empty cart page and i refresh the page, the JS is working and refresh the page, but if it's from the cart page with product and i remove the product then it's not working.
